# use block chain without using bitcoin based payment

Tags: private-blockchains, decentralized-assets

I am beginner to bitcoin. 
I intend to develop a proprietary mobile app to trade some kind of commodity among multiple users( with a optional arbitrator in between but not a must).

I got interested in bitcoin technology since it offers the block chain with hashing and signature to establish distributed ledgers. I want to track the app transaction between multiple users by leveraging the block chain and hashing mechanism of blocks. I will customize the contents of blocks with my proprietary stuff.

I do not want to use bitcoin method of payment for my mobile application transaction. This will eliminate the need of mining and maintain a bitcoin wallet. Users can use any kind of payment outside bitcoins

Is this possible? How can I leverage appropriate components of bitcoin open source API and which one should I use?